# C++ 11 Concurrency pass shared memory object as reference rejected

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex, shared-memory

I find that Visual Sudio 2012 makes std::mutex copy constructor private, so I think it can only be passed by reference or pointer, and I test both of them, but to my surprise, the pointer style pass, while the reference style rejected by the compiler, and it says: 
" error C2248: 'std::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::mutex' ", so the compiler assumes that I try to copy the std::mutex, but in fact I pass it by reference! Anyone have a experience about that? I list my code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

struct SharedMemory 
{
public:
    int s;
    std::mutex mutex;

public:
    SharedMemory( int s = 1 ) : s(s){}

    void write( int s )
    {
        mutex.lock();
        this->s = s;
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    int read()
    {
        int tmp;
        mutex.lock();
        tmp = this->s;
        mutex.unlock();
        return tmp;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << read() << std::endl;
    }
};

void modify( SharedMemory& sm, int i ) // **must use the pointer to the shared memory**
{
    //sm->write(i);
    sm.write(i);
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    SharedMemory sm;
    SharedMemory& tmp = sm;
    std::vector< std::thread > vec;
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) 
    {
        vec.push_back( std::thread( modify, sm, i ) );
        sm.print();
    }

    for( auto& it : vec ) it.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::ref(sm)` should work, right?

Comment: Since c++ uses Copy on Write passing by reference would work until one process tried to write to the shared memory. At this point rather than both processes looking at one location for shared memory one process would look at location A and the other to location B which has defeated the purpose of the shared memory.